# How to propagate "model covariance" into a covariance matrix?

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, predictive-models, optimization, goodness-of-fit

I have a theory $f$ (actually a set of coupled non-linear differential equations) that, from a vector of $n$ initial conditions $\vec x$, is able to predict $m$ values $f(\vec x) = \vec y$.

I can measure $\vec y$ in nature with some covariance $\mathbf \Sigma$. I want to find the initial conditions $\vec x$ that most likely explain $\vec y$ according to my theory $f$. So I will obtain an estimate $\hat x$ using some sort of $\chi^2$ minimization such as

$$\hat x = \underset{\vec x}{\arg\min} \; \sum {\frac{\left[ f(\vec x) - \vec y \right]^2}{\mathbf \Sigma^2}}.$$

I know from my theory that two measurable variables $y_i$ and $y_j$ co-vary. I can simulate $f(\vec x)$ for many different choices of $\vec x$ and find that their covariance is strong. However, they are measured independently of each other, so their measured covariance is 0.

How can I propagate the simulated covariance into the objective function?